# Generating Predictable Secure Random Numbers

Tags: java, random, secure-random

How can I instantiate a predictable and secure random number generator which will generate consistent random numbers across Java versions and operating systems?

The following code used to work in Java 8 but no longer works in Java 10:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class PredictableRandom {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PredictableRandom predictableRandom = new PredictableRandom();
    predictableRandom.execute();
}

private void execute() {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    System.out.println(secureRandom.getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println(secureRandom.getProvider());
    long seed = 12345678L;
    secureRandom.setSeed(seed);
    System.out.println(secureRandom.nextLong());
    SecureRandom secureRandom2 = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom2.setSeed(seed);
    System.out.println(secureRandom2.nextLong());
}
}
```

In Java 8 - good, different random objects generate the same random number:

```
SHA1PRNG
SUN version 1.8
3325995872096263519
3325995872096263519
```

In Java 10 - bad, different random objects generate different random number:

```
DRBG
SUN version 10
-3526685326322256981
-2373261409119309182
```

Comment: The entire point of **secure** random is that numbers should be unpredictable. If you want predictability, don't use secure version.

Comment: How come it worked in Java 8 and doesn't work in Java 10? Is there someway to configure secure random to remain backward compatible?

Comment: @lyaffe How come? You see the answer in your own output: The default implementation was changed from `SHA1PRNG` to `DRBG`. Obviously, `DRBG` is more *secure*, as you're now getting unpredictable results. `SHA1PRNG` wasn't. If you want to keep using `SHA1PRNG`, specifically ask for it.

Comment: The fact that `SHA1PRNG` isn't truly secure, and `DRBG` is (more) secure, is valid according to the contract of [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), as specified in the javadoc: *"Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. **Other implementations may produce true random numbers**, and yet others may use a combination of both techniques"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is get the an instance of secure random using the old algorithm using [SecureRandom.getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)).

Sample code below.  You should think about weather or not this is the behaviour that you actually want.

```
    public void example() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        secureRandom.setSeed(12345678L);
        System.out.println(secureRandom.nextLong());

    }
    {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        secureRandom.setSeed(12345678L);
        System.out.println(secureRandom.nextLong());

    }

}
```

This spits out:

```
3325995872096263519
3325995872096263519
```

Just like you were looking for.

Comment: That was it. Not sure how I missed it before.

Comment: @lyaffe it would be nifty if you checked this as answered :P